# Angular : TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I am using JHipster Auth-guard. I am trying to trigger canActivate for a user who does not have permission for a route.

I can't for the life of me see where it goes wrong. Console says .then() is undefined at code below. I tried console logging the principal and it is not undefined. Fellow stackflowers, can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

```
checkLogin(authorities: string[], url: string): Promise<boolean> {
    var principal = this.principal;

    return Promise.resolve(principal.identity().then((account) => {



   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at AuthGuard.checkLogin (auth-guard.ts:27)
    at AuthGuard.canActivate (auth-guard.ts:21)
```

My code:

```
app.module

    const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '**',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        resolve: {
            data: DashboardService
        }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpModule,
        CdkTableModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,

        NgxChartsModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        ProjectDashboardService, AuthGuard, Principal, StateStorageService
    ]
})
```

Auth-guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Principal } from './principal.service';
import { StateStorageService } from './state-storage.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private principal: Principal,
        private stateStorageService: StateStorageService) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Promise<boolean> {

        const authorities = route.data['authorities'];
        // We need to call the checkLogin / and so the principal.identity() function, to ensure,
        // that the client has a principal too, if they already logged in by the server.
        // This could happen on a page refresh.
        return this.checkLogin(authorities, state.url);
    }

    checkLogin(authorities: string[], url: string): Promise<boolean> {
        var principal = this.principal;

        return Promise.resolve(principal.identity().then((account) => {

            if (!authorities || authorities.length === 0) {
                return true;
            }

            if (account) {
                return principal.hasAnyAuthority(authorities).then((response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            }

            this.stateStorageService.storeUrl(url);
            //this.router.navigate(['accessdenied']);
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            return false;
        }));
    }
}
```

principal service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class Principal {
    private userIdentity: any;
    private authenticated = false;
    private authenticationState = new Subject<any>();

    constructor(

    ) { }

    authenticate(identity) {
        this.userIdentity = identity;
        this.authenticated = identity !== null;
        this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
    }

    hasAnyAuthority(authorities: string[]): Promise<boolean> {
        return Promise.resolve(this.hasAnyAuthorityDirect(authorities));
    }

    hasAnyAuthorityDirect(authorities: string[]): boolean {
        if (!this.authenticated || !this.userIdentity || !this.userIdentity.authorities) {
            return false;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < authorities.length; i++) {
            if (this.userIdentity.authorities.includes(authorities[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    hasAuthority(authority: string): Promise<boolean> {
        if (!this.authenticated) {
            return Promise.resolve(false);
        }

        return this.identity().then((id) => {
            return Promise.resolve(id.authorities && id.authorities.includes(authority));
        }, () => {
            return Promise.resolve(false);
        });
    }

    identity(force?: boolean): Promise<any> {
        if (force === true) {
            this.userIdentity = undefined;
        }

        // check and see if we have retrieved the userIdentity data from the server.
        // if we have, reuse it by immediately resolving
        if (this.userIdentity) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.userIdentity);
        }

    }

    isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        return this.authenticated;
    }

    isIdentityResolved(): boolean {
        return this.userIdentity !== undefined;
    }

    getAuthenticationState(): Observable<any> {
        return this.authenticationState.asObservable();
    }

    getImageUrl(): String {
        return this.isIdentityResolved() ? this.userIdentity.imageUrl : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The result of *calling* principal is undefined. Are you sure the parentheses are in the right places?

Comment: Your `identity` function does not return anything if `this.userIdentity` is falsey, which means it's returning undefined and therefore you can't call `.then` on it

Comment: @user184994 You are right. My tunnelvision made me miss this, so i should add this :         if (this.userIdentity) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.userIdentity);
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(false);
        }

Comment: Thanks for your help  @user184994. It worked when i returned false. 

Solution:
Change the return in principal.identity() so it returns false if the userIdentity is false and removing this          if (!authorities || authorities.length === 0) {
                return true;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @user184994. It worked when i returned false. Solution: Change the return in

> principal.identity()

so it returns false if the userIdentity is false and removing this

> if (!authorities || authorities.length === 0) { return true; }